# i want to hide or show button according to table data

Tags: javascript, php

I want to hide or show button according to table data. If data is 0 then button show else hide

```
<?php

$variable="SELECT * FROM tabel";
$variable1=mysql_query($variable);
$count=1;
$variable2=mysql_fetch_array($variable1)

?>
<?php
$t=$variable2['paid'];
?>
<script>
    var payment_link='<?php echo $t ?>';
    if (payment_link=='0') {
        $('#send').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#send').show();
    }
</script>
<buttonid="send">SEND</button>
```

Comment: Note: don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore. They are old, unsecure, deprecated and removed in "latest" php versions. Switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: move the script below the `<button>`. Now you try to change something, that isn't there yet. (or wrap it in a `$( document ).ready(function() { // your code }`)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that the javascript is executed *before* the button gets even rendered. This is why javascript can't change it yet.

Two possibilities:
Move the `<script>` part below the `<button>`

or wrap it in a `$( document ).ready(function() { // your code })`:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
   var payment_link='<?php echo $t ?>';
    if (payment_link=='0') {
      $('#send').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#send').show();
    } 
});
</script>
```

Also make sure to have a space between 'button' and 'id':

```
<button id="send">SEND</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the space missing between button and id in the below line?

```
<buttonid="send">SEND</button>
```

If that is the case, please change to:

```
<button id="send">SEND</button>
```